# How to create a JSON with negative id in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

**EDIT: Sorry for not giving all info previously, now I've added it**

The output is quite simlpe, but I don't know how to reach it:

```
{
 example:
  {'-1': 'goo',
  '-2': 'foo',
  ...
  '-n': 'faa'}
}
```

This is my `df`

```
    A          id
0   goo         -1
1   foo         -2
2   fee         -3
3   fii         -4
4   faa         -5
```

I've tried this:

```
df.to_json("path")
```

But it gives me a json with positive values

How could I reverse their id to be all negatives?

Comment: You can dump whatever data you want in a json file, I'm not sure which problem you're facing? Also, show us what you already tried to do to solve this

Comment: Miss information in your question, which one is your target? Get Natural numbers and convert to negative? dump the content of dictionary into file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.set_index('id').to_json()

'{"A":{"-1":"goo","-2":"foo","-3":"fee","-4":"fii","-5":"faa"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
{'-' + k: v for k, v in x.items()}
```

where `x` is the original dict with "positive" keys.

Is that what you meant?

Edit: or if the dict `x` contains integer keys:

```py
{k * -1: v for k, v in x.items()}
```

To json:

```py
import json
json.dumps({k * -1: v for k, v in x.items()}
```

Comment: the 'k' will probably be a string so you wanna mend that :>
and in the json it looks like he's having strings again :>

Comment: I included solutions for both string and int keys

Answer (score 0):

Mmm assuming you read your json as python dictionary:

```
pos_dct = {'1': 'a', '2': 'b'}
neg_dct = {}

for key, val in dct.items():
    neg_dct [str(-1*int(key))] = val

neg_dct 
# Out[21]: {'-1': 'a', '-2': 'b'}
```

Now restore it to json